# How to get unique lines based on value of a column

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk

Following input:

```
A 13
A 12
B 17
C 33
D 344
C 24
A 5
C 99
```

I want to get only the lines where column one is unique:

```
B 17
D 344
```

A solution with `awk` would be nice, but something else is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]++ } NR!=FNR && a[$1]==1' file file
```

(the filename is passed twice).

**Edit:** If the file comes from `stdin` you need a temporary copy.  Something like this:

```
tmp="$( mktemp -t "${0##*/}"_"$$"_.XXXXXXXX )" && \
    trap 'rm -f "$tmp"' 0 HUP INT QUIT TERM || exit 1
... | tee "$tmp" | awk '...' - "$tmp"
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution I go for. Follow up question: How do I give stdout from proceeding command two times to awk? (like inputting two tims the same file)

Comment: @Michael I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind scrambling the order, then

```
sort <file> | uniq -uw 1
```

See `man uniq` for more information, but here are the important parts.

```
   -u, --unique
          only print unique lines
   -w, --check-chars=N
          compare no more than N characters in lines
```

Comment: Forgot about `-w` for `uniq`. This would be the way to go.

Comment: @Tigger One possible caveat is if the first field is not always the same number of characters long. Then it might need something more sophisticated. It's also odd that `uniq` has `-s` and `-w`, but only `-f`, and nothing analogous to only check the first N fields.

Comment: GNU coreutils' `uniq` has `-w`. Others do not.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like **awk**

```
awk '
    $1 in ARR{
        ARR[$1] = RS;
        next;
    }
    {
        ARR[$1] = $0;
    }
    END{
        for(i in ARR)
            if(ARR[i] != RS)
                print ARR[i];
    }
    ' file
```

The script put lines into array ARR with 1st field as an index and full line as a value. If array already have same index change value to «\n» (new line) sign. After the file ended prints those array's elements which value do not equal «\n»
Be informed that awk's `RS` variable is equal `newline` by default.

Or you can do it by **sed**

```
sort file |
sed '
    :a;
    $!N;
    s/\(\S\+\s\).*\n\1.*/\1\a/;
    ta;
    /\a/P;
    D;
    '
```

Comment: Nice (+1)! An explanation would be great though.

Comment: There's a slight problem if we had a line with the 2nd field as "r" and this line appeared only once in the file. Then this will be discarded by awk code, but it shouldn't per spec.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Have edited to avoid noted

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1 <file | sort | uniq -d | sed 's/^/^/' | grep -v -f /dev/stdin file
B 17
D 344
```

This first picks out the duplicated entries in the first column of the file `file` by cutting the column out, sorting it and feeding it to `uniq -d` (which will only report duplicates).

It then prefixes each resulting line with `^` to create regular expressions that are anchored to the beginning of the line. The output of the `sed` command with the given data is

```
^A
^C
```

The final `grep` reads these regular expressions and picks out all lines from the file that does not match any of them. We get `grep` to read the patterns from `sed` by using `-f /dev/stdin`.

The result will have the same order as in the original file.

Comment: For what it's worth: GNU `grep` accepts `-f -` instead of `-f /dev/stdin`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura It may do, but my `grep` doesn't.

Comment: Yup, BSD `grep` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane '
   exists $h{$F[0]} and undef $h{$F[0]},next;

   ( $h{$F[0]}, $h[@h] ) = ( $_, $F[0] );

   END{ print $h{$_} for grep { defined $h{$_} } @h }
' yourfile
```

The operation of the code looks at if the 1st field has been encountered earlier, then the key by that
name would exist in the hash, and so we go ahead and `undef` the value for this particular key, as 
there's no point in building up an array that will anyway be discarded at the end. Instead we carry the same information by a lesser memory imprint.

And in the scenario of seeing the 1st field the very 1st time, we populate the hash `%h` with the current line and simultaneously append the array `@h` with this key. We undertake this step to retain the order in which the keys were encountered. If we don't care for the order, then we can very well do away with this step.

Finally, when all input has been digested, in the end `END` block, loop over the elements of the array `@h` and from those fish out only those for whom the hash `%h` has defined values. Remember, `undef` values means must have seen more than once.